# Please help me with the solution of the following problem:

Tags: probability-distributions

Each bag in a large box contains 25 tulip bulbs. It is known that 60% of the bags contain bulbs for 5 red and 20 yellow tulips, while the remaining 40% of the bags contain bulbs for 15 red and 10 yellow tulips. A bag is selected at random and a bulb taken at random from this bag is planted.
(a) What is the probability that it will be a yellow tulip?
(b) Given that it is yellow, what is the conditional probability it comes from a bag that contained 5 red and 20 yellow bulbs?

Comment: Please edit the title so that it gives more information about the problem. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let Bag 1 contain (5R 20Y) and Bag 2 containn (15R, 10Y)

$P(Bag1)*P(Y/Bag1) = 0.6\times\frac{20}{25} = 0.6\times 0.8 = .48$

$P(Bag2)*P(Y/Bag2) = 0.4\times\frac{10}{25} = 0.4\times 0.4 = .16$

Part I :

$P(Y) = 0.48+.16 = 0.64$

$P(Bag1/Y) = \dfrac{P(Bag1)*P(Y/Bag1)}{(P(Bag1)*P(Y/Bag1)+P(Bag2)*P(Y/Bag2)}$

Part II:

$P(Bag1/Y) = \frac{0.48}{0.64} = 0.75$